# Remove everything between second and second last occurance of match

Tags: python, linux, perl

I have string which I would like to format. I would like to remove everything between second ; and second last ;.

Input

```
cellular organisms;Eukaryota;Opisthokonta;Metazoa;Eumetazoa;Bilateria;Protostomia;Ecdysozoa;Panarthropoda;Arthropoda;Mandibulata;Pancrustacea;Hexapoda;Insecta;Dicondylia;Pterygota;Neoptera;Endopterygota;Coleoptera;Polyphaga;Cucujiformia;Tenebrionoidea;Tenebrionidae;Tenebrionidae incertae sedis;Tribolium;Tribolium castaneum;
```

Output

```
cellular organisms;Eukaryota;Tribolium castaneum;
```

I have tried usind sed.

```sh
$ sed 's/;[^;]*//' <<<"cellular organisms;Eukaryota;Opisthokonta;Metazoa;Eumetazoa;Bilateria;Protostomia;Ecdysozoa;Panarthropoda;Arthropoda;Mandibulata;Pancrustacea;Hexapoda;Insecta;Dicondylia;Pterygota;Neoptera;Endopterygota;Coleoptera;Polyphaga;Cucujiformia;Tenebrionoidea;Tenebrionidae;Tenebrionidae incertae sedis;Tribolium;Tribolium castaneum;"
```

produce

```
cellular organisms;Opisthokonta;Metazoa;Eumetazoa;Bilateria;Protostomia;Ecdysozoa;Panarthropoda;Arthropoda;Mandibulata;Pancrustacea;Hexapoda;Insecta;Dicondylia;Pterygota;Neoptera;Endopterygota;Coleoptera;Polyphaga;Cucujiformia;Tenebrionoidea;Tenebrionidae;Tenebrionidae incertae sedis;Tribolium;Tribolium castaneum;
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regexp in Perl

```sh
perl -pE's/;.*?\K;.*(?=;.*;)//' <<<'cellular organisms;Eukaryota;Opisthokonta;...;Tribolium;Tribolium castaneum;'
```

Answer (score 2):

With such a simple selection of fields, you can use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to separate the string into fields, pick out the fields you want, and put them back together with [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html).

Note that you must provide a negative number for the third parameter to `split` to prevent it from discarding trailing empty fields.

It looks like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = 'cellular organisms;Eukaryota;Opisthokonta;Metazoa;Eumetazoa;Bilateria;Protostomia;Ecdysozoa;Panarthropoda;Arthropoda;Mandibulata;Pancrustacea;Hexapoda;Insecta;Dicondylia;Pterygota;Neoptera;Endopterygota;Coleoptera;Polyphaga;Cucujiformia;Tenebrionoidea;Tenebrionidae;Tenebrionidae incertae sedis;Tribolium;Tribolium castaneum;';

my $ss = join ';', (split /;/, $s, -1)[0,1,-2,-1];

print $ss, "\n";
```

**output**

```
cellular organisms;Eukaryota;Tribolium castaneum;
```